Errorbars in a seaborn.PairGrid plot
I have the following code:
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x1','x2','x3','label'])
for i in range(100):
    Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'1']

Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'2']
Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'3']
Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'4']
Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'5']

DataErr = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x1UppErr','x1LowErr','x2UppErr','x2LowErr','x3UppErr','x3LowErr','label'])

# for i in range(100):
#     DataErr.loc[len(DataErr.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'1']

DataErr.loc[len(DataErr.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'2']
DataErr.loc[len(DataErr.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'3']
DataErr.loc[len(DataErr.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'4']
DataErr.loc[len(DataErr.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'5']

# We will create the grid ourselves instead of using seaborn's utility
g = sns.PairGrid(Data.loc[Data['label'] == '1'], corner=True)
g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, fill=True)

# Since we are adding the data piecewise, we need to keep track of which ones got which colors
palette = sns.color_palette()
legend_labels = {'1': (palette[0], 'o')}

# Add each dataset piecewise
for i, label in enumerate(Data['label'].unique()):
    print(type(i))
    print(i)
    print(type(label))
    print(label)
    # Don't re-add group 1 again
    if label == '1':
        continue
    # Add the data, including the edge color
    g.data = Data.loc[Data['label'] == label]
    g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot, marker='s', edgecolor='black')
    # Track which color and marker we plotted with
    legend_labels[label] = (palette[i % len(palette)], 's')

# Add the legend with the colors and markers
# This line issues a warning you can ignore
g.add_legend(handles=[
    plt.Line2D(
        [], [], ls='', color=colormarker[0], marker=colormarker[1], label=label
    ) for label, colormarker in legend_labels.items()
])

plt.show()

which gives the following output:

My data is in the Data pandas.DataFrame and I have randomised asymmetric errors for the data points 2,3,4 and 5 in the DataErr pandas.DataFrame. I want to add the asymmetric errors in the DataErr dataframe in the pairgrid plot shown in the image. How do I do that?
I have started by trying to sort out the asymmetric errors in lists in the following way:
x1UppErr = []
x1LowErr = []
x2UppErr = []
x2LowErr = []
x3UppErr = []
x3LowErr = []

for index,row in DataErr:
    x1UppErr.append(row['x1UppErr'])
    x1LowErr.append(row['x1LowErr'])
    x2UppErr.append(row['x2UppErr'])
    x2LowErr.append(row['x2LowErr'])
    x3UppErr.append(row['x3UppErr'])
    x3LowErr.append(row['x3LowErr'])

I was planning to either use the g.map_lower()  to in some way add these errors or in some way loop through the axes in g but I don't know how to do that or if this even is the right way to proceed.
